# Trying to create datetime index for monthly rainfall vector

Tags: matlab, datetime, indexing

I have a vector of data that is 564 elements long representing 1970/Jan rainfall, 1970/feb rainfall etc.

I want to index the vector using datetime. 
I've tried to create a datetime array like this

```
years  = linspace(1970,2015,47);
years  = repelem(years,12)';
months = [1:12];
months = repmat(months,1,47)';
day    = 1;
datetime = datetime(years,months,day)
```

But this gives me the error -

"Error using datetime (line 581)
Year, month, day, hour, and minute components must be integer values.

Error in Station_plots (line 32)
   datetime = datetime(years,months,day)".

Am I going about solving this problem correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 46 instead of 47. Simple Math